# How to create Task ( project.task ) under specific customer (res.partner ) in ODOO?

Tags: ios, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

How to create Task ( **project.task** ) for specific customer (**res.partner** ) in ODOO / OpenERP ?

I am sending below input parameter for creating Task under customer :

```
(
Sample Database,
1,
Pass4ODOO,
project.task,
create,
{
    "categ_ids" =     (
                (
            6,
            0,
                        (
            )
        )
    );
    description = "";
    name = sample task;
    priority = 0;
    sequence = 0;
},
12
)
```

In above input parameter 12 is customer id. Under this customer i want to create task.

Does any body know this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not describe how you are interfacing with Odoo, but I looks like you are using some library performing XML-RPC calls.

The `create()` API function accepts a dictionary with the data for the new record to be created.

It looks like that the dictionary after the `create,` argument should also include a `partner_id=12;` key, instead of being an additional argument at the end of the call.

Comment: Thanks daniel. You are right. We won't need to give a additional argument at the end of the call.

Comment: Do you know about this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024408/how-to-fetch-calendar-calendar-event-meetings-for-particular-date-in-odoo