# How to fetch Calendar (calendar.event) meetings for particular date in ODOO?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

Does anybody know how to fetch Calendar **(calendar.event)** meetings/events for particular date OR "from date to date" in ODOO ?

Till yet i have read meetings using meeting Ids as follow:

```
(
Sample DB Name,
1,
Password,
calendar.event,
read,
(
125
)
)
```

In above input parameter 125 is my meeting Id. So i get records of that particular meeting id. But now i want the meetings record based on dates.

So how can i achieve this ? What will be the inputs for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the Odoo External API.
The `read` method is to be used when you know the `id` for the records to fetch.

To get records based on a condition you should use [`search_read`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html#search-and-read) and pass it a [domain expression](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#domains) instead of the record `ids`.

As an illustration, the domain you nedd could look like:

```
[['start_datetime', '>=', '2015-04-29 00:00:00'], 
 ['start_datetime', '<',  '2015-04-30 00:00:00']]
```

Comment: Thanks daniel. This is life saving for me.

Comment: Daniel can you please suggest me how to do this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051856/how-to-achieve-send-by-email-functionality-in-quotations-and-sales-order-m