# How to achieve "Send by email" functionality in "Quotations" and "Sales Order" module in ODOO?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I am developing ODOO application in iOS.
I want to achieve "Send by email" functionality in "Quotations" and "Sales Order" module in ODOO.

So is there any API available to achieve this functionality ?

Or shall i generate PDF programmatically in iOS and send this by using MFMailComposeViewController class ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is best to reuse the Odoo feature.
The button calls a method of the Sale Order model.
You can identify the method's name if you activate the Developer Mode:

[image: Send by Email button]

The method is `action_quotation_send`, and it is available in the External API just like `write` is.

Unfortunately this particular method opens a wizard: it just prepares some data and then returns an action to the webclient to open the "wizard" dialog, and the actual operation will only be performed there, with its "Send" button.

To have a fully automated procedure, usable from a single API call, you will need to implement yourself a method. There `website_sale` official module does [something similar](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/website_sale/controllers/main.py#L802-L825), so I recommend looking to extract the relevant code for your use case.

Comment: Thanks daniel.. means you want to say that i want to implement another method in web to send mail  and from iOS application call that method... ?